# Como posso relacionar 3 tabelas utilizando Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Ola, preciso de uma ajuda com Relationships.

Estou estudando Laravel e me deparei com esse problema.

Eu poderia usar Join, mas queria uma forma mais simples e utilizar as relações do Laravel para fazer esse tipo de busca.

Tenho 3 Tabelas conforme imagem.

[image: Tables]

Estou querendo fazer uma seguinte busca.

`Cargo::find(2)->colaborador->user;`

Buscar todos os usuários cujo cargo seja o id 2.

Dessa forma não funcionou.

---

`Cargo::find(2)->colaborador;`

Esse funciona.

Busca todos os colaboradores que preciso, porém essa tabela tem apenas as FK. Assim não consigo pegar nome, email, etc.

---

Abaixo coloquei minhas models simplificadas apenas com o ralacionamento entre as tabelas que fiz.

Posso estar errado no relacionamento também.

Colaborador Model.

```
<?php
class Colaborador extends Model
{
    protected $table = "colaboradores";
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function cargo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Cargo::class);
    }
}
```

Cargo Model

```
<?php
class Cargo extends Model
{
    protected $table = "cargos";
    public function colaborador()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Colaborador::class);
    }
}
```

User Model

```
<?php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    public function colaborador()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Colaborador::class);
    }

}
```

Obrigado desde já!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta fazer as seguintes relations:

No model colaborador:

```
 class Colaborador extends Model
    {
        protected $table = "colaboradores";

        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
        }
    }
```

No model cargo:

```
class Cargo extends Model
{
    protected $table = "cargos";

    public function colaboradores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Colaborador::class, 'cargo_id');
    }
}
```

Depois de definir as relations, pode fazer a query da seguinte maneira:

```
Cargo::find(2)->colaboradores()->with('user)->get();
```

Terá como retorno a relação `colaboradores` e, na aba `relations`, aparece o usuário relacionado com este model de colaboradores, mais ou menos assim:

```
Collection {#214 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Colaborador {#209 ▼
      #fillable: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: "pgsql"
      #table: "colaboradors"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "user_id" => 1
        "cargo_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2019-05-24 01:34:33"
        "updated_at" => "2019-05-24 01:34:33"
      ]
      #original: array:5 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "user" => User {#222 ▼
          #fillable: array:3 [▶]
          #hidden: array:2 [▶]
          #casts: array:1 [▶]
          #connection: "pgsql"
          #table: "users"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:8 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "name" => "Nome do usuario"
            "email" => "email@email.com"
            "email_verified_at" => null
            "password" => "password"
            "remember_token" => null
            "created_at" => "2019-05-24 01:32:03"
            "updated_at" => "2019-05-24 01:32:03"
          ]
          #original: array:8 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

Para acessar o `user` na relationship, basta usar um laço de repetição:

```
foreach($colaboradores as $colaborador){
    $user = $colaborador->user;
    //
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.
Mas gostaria de saber onde encontro mais sobre esse with().
```Cargo::find(2)->colaboradores()->with('user)->get();```
Não encontrei ele na documentação, não achei em queru builder ou Relationships.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading